# List of Ruby on Rails 3.X Resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resources

I am looking for NEW Ruby on Rails resource websites (Screencasts, Tutorials, etc) some of what I found are Outdated. So for Ruby on Rails 3.X please.

I have:

- http://railscasts.com/
- http://railsforzombies.org (witch is...AWESOME, a kick-start)
- http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend newer [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) and great [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I've been reading the RailsTutorial for Rails 3 and think it's amazing.

http://railstutorial.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing Rails app to upgrade, you'll probably also want to check out Jeremy McAnally's [Rails 3 Upgrade
Handbook](http://www.railsupgradehandbook.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Peepcode are good too. Not a free resource

http://peepcode.com/